# Strange npm update behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I shall mention that, I am a newbie to Angular and NPM.

I have two projects, both are created using Angular-CLI.
In one of them when I execute `npm update --save` the dependencies get updated (including `@angular` dependencies from `^5.2.0` to `^5.2.3`) in `package.json` file, but in the other one nothing gets updated.

I shall mention that both projects reside in a single computer, and even the project whose `package.json` is not updated runs using `Angular 5.2.3` (the files in `/node_modules/@angular/...` are from 5.2.3 version of Angular).

I even have tested `ncu`, but got same results.

I can not understand why one project dependencies gets updated, but other ones does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only updating the `package.json` of the actual project.

`/node_modules/@angular/...` are dependencies.
The version there is from the included model.

The model have to update his dependencies if in the `/node_modules/@angular/.../package.json` should be an other version.

For Example: this is the `package.json` from angular:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/package.json

they have to update there own project and after you have to update your project with `npm update --save`, if the `package.json` in the angular model should change.

Comment: I know that, but the strange thing is one project's `package.json` gets updated, but the other one does not. Why is that?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh could you please show the two `package.json` files?

Comment: Although the problem is solved, and I don't know how. Because this was the only answer, I accept it.